# How can I copy several columns from table1 into table2 while ALSO defining certain static rows in table2?

Tags: sql-server, insert, copy

I understand how to copy a column from one table into another, but I need to do that + also define the values of extra columns in table2 according to local variables within my stored procedure.

Is there a way to do this in one go? Thanks so much for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you can simply select the variables' values inline with the columns from the second table, like so:

```
-- Pseudo-declarations just to clarify example
CREATE TABLE t1
(
  col1 INT,
  col2 INT,
  col3 INT,
  colA VARCHAR,
  colB VARCHAR
)

CREATE TABLE t2
(
  col1 INT,
  col2 INT,
  col3 INT
)

DECLARE @varA VARCHAR
DECLARE @varB VARCHAR

[...]

-- You can select whatever other values you need alongside columns from the source table
INSERT INTO t1 (col1, col2, col3, colA, colB)
SELECT col1, col2, col3, @varA, @varB
FROM t2
```

Comment: Looks right - but as an aside, I'd never declare a bare `varchar` - it has an insane default length.

Comment: Yeah, like... 1. Agreed. Hence my comment describing the declarations as "pseudo". :)